# Why do I get an encrypted result even though theres no input?

Tags: php, html, encryption

So i'm just playing around with PHP trying to create a Encrypt word and decrypt system. So here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Encrypt</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="encrypt-in">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<br>
<?php


$in = (isset($_POST['encrypt-in']) ? $_POST['encrypt-in'] : '');;

$hashedin = password_hash($in, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";

echo "Encrypted input: "."<br>"."$hashedin";

?> 
</form>
<hr>
<h1>Decrypt</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="decrypt-in">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
$out = (isset($_POST['decrypt-in']) ? $_POST['decrypt-in'] : '');;
$hashedout = password_verify($out, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
echo "Decrypted input: "."<br>"."$hashedout";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

And when running the example I get an encrypted result like so.

[image]

Even though theres no input. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you can't decrypt the result of password_hash(), you can only verify that a new entered value matches the existing hashed value

Comment: So I can only figure out if its true or false? @MarkBaker

Comment: That's right: [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) returns a boolean

Comment: So create my salt and then concatenate? Is that a way I can encrypt and decrypt input? @MarkBaker

Comment: If you want this for passwords, then you don't want to decrypt, you only need to verify that the password entered on the login screen matches the one stored for that user

Comment: If you want to encrypt data that can subsequently be decrypted, then use the [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) library

Answer (score 1):

The hashing algorithm you are using will give you a hash for an empty string.

This is expected behaviour.

Comment: So what do you recommend me use? Just use a salt and concatenate it?

Comment: I recommend that you stop treating "Empty strings generate a hash" as a problem. If you want to prevent empty input, then test for empty input and throw an error instead of generating a hash from an empty string. Don't add a salt, `password_hash` will generate a salt automatically.

Comment: Well I'm not trying to store or use it on passwords. I'm just trying to encrypt a string.

Answer (score 0):

u need to add this condition !empty($_POST['encrypt-in'])

$in = (isset($_POST['encrypt-in']) && !empty($_POST['encrypt-in'])) ? $_POST['encrypt-in'] : '');;